# What is this macro for at the beginning of a class definition?

Tags: c++, class, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm looking through the source of a library and many classes are defined using the following form

```
class THING_API ClassName 
{
...
```

Jumping to the macro definition . . .

```
#ifndef THING_API
 #define THING_API   /**< This macro is added to all public class declarations. */
#endif
```

What could this be for, and is it a common technique?

Comment: If I had to guess, you are on a non Windows machine and on Windows this macro would expand to something like `__declspec(dllexport)`, right?

Comment: If you look at the [BNF grammar](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/), then you can figure out some of the things that the standard allows for, including a namespace specification and the alignas keyword as well as various attributes seen in the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me very much like export macro, which is required when building a shared library (.dll) on Windows. When compiling with MSVC, You have to put `__declspec(export)` in that spot when building a library, and `__declspec(import)` when building its client. This is achieved like so:

```
#if COMPILING_DLL
    #define THING_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define THING_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Then you define `COMPILING_DLL` for the library project, and leave it undefined for all other projects. And if you're not on Windows or compiling a static library, you need to define it blank like it's done in your question.

P. S. Other Windows compilers use their own keywords instead of `__declspec(dllimport)`, but the principle remains.

Comment: Do you need to mark classes like this for MSVC?  I'm familiar with doing this for functions that are callable across a DLL boundary but don't remember seeing it being applied to classes too.

Comment: @simonc: it's required for all exported symbols - both classes and plain functions. If you don't mark a class as export, you will get `unresolved external symbol` when trying to use it from another project. Alternatively, you can only export certain class members.

Comment: Aha, I searched for other `#define THING_API` strings and found code exactly like this. When you ask XCode to jump to a definition, it only gives you the relevant one, but the other definitions do what you describe.

Answer (score 3):

One possible use would be to allow you to conditionally mark the class as callable from other libraries in a cross-platform library.

```
class ClassName
```

would be callable on Windows using MSVC but you'd need

```
class __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) ClassName
```

for linux using gcc.

In this case, `THING_API` might be defined like

```
#ifdef _WIN32
# define THING_API
#else
# define THING_API __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty macros like that are often used so that other parsers can gather information from the headers.

Apple has the empty `IBOutlet` macro which the Interface Builder uses to allow you to connect variables to UI items in its GUI, and I think Qt uses the technique for their "moc" precompiler.